# webpack does not throw any error code

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack build fails without any descriptive  error but only giving the following message

**Failed to compile with 1 errors**

How can I get a more descriptive error?

Comment: webpack 1 or 2?

Comment: @cktang This is webpack 2.

Comment: `webpack --display-error-details --verbose ...`

Comment: I am using webpack through an express server so looking into a plugin approach.

Comment: @charith look at `quiet` and `noInfo`: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-middleware#usage

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `webpack-dev-middleware` in my development server, which was generating the same error as you were seeing. By configuring is with `{ quiet: false }` it would output a lot more information.

I'm sure this is the same as doing `webpack` without `--quiet`.